# Require module that uses a singleton array

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, singleton, electron

I want to create a really basic CRUD (sort-of) example app, to see how things work.

I want to store items (items of a shopping-list) in an array, using functions defined in my *listService.js* such as `addItem(item)`, `getAllItems()` and so on.

My problems come when using the same module (*listService.js*) in different files, because it creates the array, in which it stores the data, multiple times, and I want it to be like a static "global" (but not a global variable) array.

*listService.js* looks like this:

```
    const items = [];

    function addItem (item) {
        items.push(item);
    }

    function getItems () {
        return items;
    }

    module.exports = {addItem, getItems};
```

and I want to use it in *mainWindowScript.js* and *addWindowScript.js*, in *addWindowScript.js* to add the elements I want to add to the array, and in *mainWindowScript.js* to get the elements and put them in a table. (I will implement later on Observer pattern to deal with adding in table when needed)

*addWindowScript.js* looks something like this:

```
    const electron = require('electron');
    const {ipcRenderer} = electron;

    const service = require('../../service/listService.js');

    const form = document.querySelector('form');
    form.addEventListener('submit', submitForm);

    function submitForm(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        const item = document.querySelector("#item").value;

        service.addItem(item);
        console.log(service.getItems());
        // This prints well all the items I add

        // ...
    }
```

and *mainWindowScript.js* like this:

```
    const electron = require('electron');

    const service = require('../../service/listService.js');

    const buttonShowAll = document.querySelector("#showAllBtn")
    buttonShowAll.addEventListener("click", () => {
        console.log(service.getItems());
        // This just shows an empty array, after I add the items in the add window
    });
```

In Java or C#, or C++ or whatever I would just create a Class for each of those and in main I'd create an instance of the Service and pass a reference of it to the windows. How can I do something similar here ?

When I first wrote the example (from a youtube [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kN1Czs0m1SU)) I handled this by 
sending messages through the *ipcRenderer* to the main module, and then sending it forward to the other window, but I don't want to deal with this every time there's a signal from one window to another.

```
    ipcRenderer.send('item:add', item);
```

and in main

```
    ipcMain.on('item:add', (event, item) => {
        mainWindow.webContents.send('item:add', item);
    })
```

So, to sum up, I want to do something like : require the module, use the function wherever the place and have only one instance of the object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> require the module, use the function wherever the place and have only one instance of the object.

TL:DR - no, that isn't possible.

Long version: Nature of Electron is *multi process*, code you runs in main process (node.js side) and renderer (chromium browser) is runnning in different process. So even you require same module *file*, object created memory in each process is *different*. There is no way to share object between process except synchrnonize objects via ipc communication. There are couple of handful synchronization logic modules out there, or you could write your module do those job like

```
module.js

if (//main process)
// setup object
//listen changes from renderer, update object, broadcast to renderer again

else (//rendere process)
//send changes to main
//listen changes from main
```

but either cases you can't get away from ipc.

Comment: Got it, thank you! I forgot Chromium is using different processes for every window. I think my solutions are to store the items in a file / database, or do all things in the same window or do as you say, listen for the changes in the main script, right?

Comment: yes, it's up to you how to synchronize object over. Just need to take care between processes.